# Shuffle the contents of Text Boxes

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get 10 different inputs in TextBoxes to be displayed in a randomized order.

I split 2 processes to make it easier to understand:

1. Button puts numbers in random orders from 1-10(works)
2. Button should replace the numbers with the contents of the TextBoxes(doesn't work)

[Here is the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6x6S.png)
/ Here is the code:

```
    Public tblRandom As New DataTable

    Private Sub btnRandom_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
        Dim r As New Random
        Dim tblRandom As New DataTable

        tblRandom.Columns.Add("Order")
        tblRandom.Constraints.Add("pk", tblRandom.Columns(0), True)

        While tblRandom.Rows.Count < 10
            Dim newrow As Object = r.Next(10) + 1
            Try
                tblRandom.Rows.Add(CStr(newrow))
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End While

        dgvRandom.DataSource = tblRandom
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnReplace_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReplace.Click
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvRandom.Rows
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                If cell.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim i As Integer = 0
                    While i < 10
                        i += 1
                        If cell.Value.ToString = i Then
                            cell.Value = ActiveControl.Tag(i)
                        End If
                    End While
                End If
            Next
        Next
        dgvRandom.DataSource = tblRandom
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: The UI doesn't look like a datagrid. Are they just textboxes?

Comment: the datagrid is the grey area on the right side ^^

Comment: In the Replace button click event, you should be looping over the datatable's rows not over the datagridviews'.

Comment: @Robin33 - How is this code working with the textboxes?

Comment: @Enigmativity through tags

```cell.Value = ActiveControl.Tag(i)```

Comment: @preciousbetine changed it to the datatable, but that hasn't solved the problem :/

Comment: @Robin33 - How is `ActiveControl` being set? You should really provide a [mcve] when asking questions.

Comment: @Robin33 - I have a solution for you that eliminates a boat-load of code, and it stops you needing to rely on `.Tag` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part you can do:

```vb
Public tblRandom As DataTable
Private ReadOnly rand As New Random

Private Sub btnRandom_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRandom.Click
    tblRandom?.Dispose()
    tblRandom = New DataTable

    tblRandom.Columns.Add("Order")
    tblRandom.Constraints.Add("pk", tblRandom.Columns(0), True)

    Dim nums As New List(Of Integer)

    While nums.Count < 10
        Dim num = rand.Next(1, 11)
        If Not nums.Contains(num) Then
            nums.Add(num)
        End If
    End While

    nums.ForEach(Sub(n) tblRandom.Rows.Add(n))

    dgvRandom.DataSource = tblRandom
End Sub
```

As for the second part, you just need to do:

```vb
Private Sub btnReplace_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReplace.Click
    For Each row As DataRow In tblRandom.Rows
        'Assuming the text boxes are hosted by the Form.
        Dim txt = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).
            Where(Function(x) x.Tag?.ToString = row(0).ToString).
            FirstOrDefault

        If txt IsNot Nothing Then
            row(0) = txt.Text
        End If
    Next
    tblRandom.AcceptChanges()
End Sub
```

Comment: The `If Not nums.Contains(num) Then` method to add unique numbers to random positions isn't a very efficient way. It's better to do `Enumerable.Range(1, 10).OrderBy(Function (n) rand.Next()).ToList()` to get a shuffled list.

Comment: @Enigmativity Agree. However, and just in case if this was an assignment and what the OP is allowed/not allowed to do. I put it this way. Actually I was hesitating to use Linq at all and I had a plan B to change it. The OP's deleted comment was useful because he pointed out my point :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your goal here is to take the text in 10 textboxes and shuffled their content. The `DataGrid` seems to be a temporary location that you're using during the shuffle.

There's a much easier way that avoids all that. Try this code:

```
Private _random = New Random()

Private Sub BtnRandom_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRandom.Click
    Dim tbs As TextBox() = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5, TextBox6, TextBox7, TextBox8, TextBox9, TextBox10}
    Dim text = tbs.Select(Function(tb) tb.Text).OrderBy(Function(t) _random.Next()).ToList()
    For Each x In tbs.Zip(text, Function(tb, t) New With {.tb = tb, .t = t})
        x.tb.Text = x.t
    Next
End Sub
```

That's it. Job done.

If you still need the `DataGrid` it would be easy to add a further line just after the `x.tb.Text = x.t` that adds the content of `x.t` to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the tag from the ActiveControl

```
cell.Value = ActiveControl.Tag(i)
```

but as you've just clicked the Replace button, isn't that the active control?

Comment: I don't think so, as far as I know it takes the object where the Tag index matches

Comment: In WinForms, ActiveControl will be the more recent control that GotFocus.  In this case it's the button just pressed, I think.  If you debug and break at that point and test the value of ActiveControl to check, what is the contents of ActiveControl.Tag(i) each time?